# make the element of a splitted array as number

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an string as this:

```
var a="12,332,22,212";
```

Now I split it to an array  like this:

```
a=a.split(",");
```

Then

```
a=["12","332","22","212"];
```

While I want to get an array like this:

```
a=[12,332,22,212];
```

Which means that the element of the array should be `Number`.

Now I have to iterate the array:

```
for(var i=0,len=a.length;i<len;i++){
  a[i]=parseFloat(a[i]);
}
```

Is there any alternative idea?

Comment: Another way could using `map`: `a = a.split(',').map(function(number) { return parseFloat(number)});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way would be to use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to do the conversion, means you need to add the missing brackets.

```
var a="12,332,22,212"; 
a = "[" + a + "]"; 
a = JSON.parse(a); //[12, 332, 22, 212]
```

Comment: Nips, why do I always miss the obvjous answers... +1, this is the best answer

Comment: Since the `map` method is not supported by all the browsers, so I think this answer is the best. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var arr = [],
var a="12,332,22,212";

arr.push.apply(arr, a.split(",").map(Number));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, use this code

```
for(var i=0; i<a.length;i++) a[i] = +a[i];
```

That would be the simplest way, to the best of my knowledge, you can also use array.map though

```
var result = a.map(function (x) { 
    return parseInt(x, 10); 
});
```

Or you can use

```
var result = a.map(function (x) {return parseFloat(x, 10);});
```

Note: credits to dheerosaur for the above code

Comment: `Array.map` doesn't require jQuery, it's part of [the ECMAScript 5 standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), as is [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)